# Data definition error haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a polymorphic list of tuples without using any imports.
i have `data ListT a = [(a,String)]
        deriving (Eq,Ord,Read,Show)`
but it keeps giving the error "cannot parse data constructor in a data/newtype declaration: [(a,String)]"

What does this error mean, and how do I prevent it.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you wanted `type ListT a = [(a, String)]`?

Comment: To avoid confusion you might want to choose a different name -  __ListT__ is used in the Haskell community for the monad transformer for the List type.

Comment: okay, thanks i'll change it

Answer (score 7):

It means that you forgot to provide the name for the value constructor. You need to change your code to the following:

```
data ListT a = ListT [(a,String)]
```

BTW, it is not a proper implementation of List Transformer.